# Inequality Question - Homogeneity

Tags: inequality, summation, substitution

Let $n>3$ and $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ be positive real numbers with $x_1x_2\cdots x_n=1$. Prove that
$$
\frac{1}{1+x_1+x_1x_2}+\frac{1}{1+x_2+x_2x_3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1+x_n+x_nx_1}>1. 
$$

I’d like to homogenize the degree of the denominator of each term but I ran out of tricks. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which tricks have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the homogenization by the following way.

Let $x_1=\frac{a_2}{a_1},$ $x_2=\frac{a_3}{a_2},$..., $x_{n-1}=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}},$ where all $a_i>0$, $a_{n+1}=a_1$ and $a_{n+2}=a_2$.

Thus, the condition gives $x_n=\frac{a_1}{a_n}$ and
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+x_1+x_2}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i}+\frac{a_{i+2}}{a_i}}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{a_i+a_{i+1}+a_{i+2}}>\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}=1.$$

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much.

Comment: Dear Michael! Really nice solution. I was trying to solve it myself but I failed and I found your solution. Let me ask you a question: In many inequality problems we do have condition $xyz=1$ or $x_1x_2\dots x_n=1$. Why in those cases the substitution which you provide is useful? Would be thankful for detailed explanation!

Comment: @ZFR Because it gives homogenization. There are another ways. For example for $xyz=1$ we can try $x=\frac{a}{b}$ if  $x=\frac{b}{a}$ does not help or we don't see how it helps.  Sometimes it's very useful. Also, $x=\frac{a^2}{bc}$ or $x=\frac{bc}{a^2}$ and else...

Comment: Do you know any materials where I can find it?

Comment: @ZFR  I think the best material it's to read solutions of best  specialists in the contests inequalities: Vasc, can_hang2007, quykhtn-qa1, mudok Abdek, and more... You can read it in the AoPS(inequalities).

Comment: Can I find them in mathstack?